# A question on Weierstrass points on algebraic curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let C be a smooth irreducible algebraic curve over $\mathbb C$, of genus $g>1$.

For $n\in \mathbb N_{>0}$, let $W_n$ be the divisor of $n$-order Weierstrass points on $C$.

**Question 1:**  in general, is there any relation between the $W_n$'s?

(a *relation* could be something algebraic as $W_1\leq W_n$ or set-theoretic  as ${\rm Supp}(W_1)\subset {\rm Supp}(W_2)$, etc..)

**Question 2:** are there particular curves with (say) $W_1$ and $W_2$ related?

If yes, what are the simplest explicit examples of such curves to have in mind.

Thank you in advance.

PS: if these questions are discussed in the literature, a good reference would be a great help.

Comment: What do you mean by the order $n$ Weierstrass points ? Those with weight at least $n$ ? Something else ?

Comment: $W_n$ is the divisor locally defined by the wronskian determinant associated to a basis of $H^0(C,K_C^{\otimes n})$.

Comment: If memory serves, in "Geometric Invariant Theory", Mumford uses the different sets $W_n$ to give one of the "covariant of points" constructions of $M_g$.  So I bet this is discussed in the text, and probably also in the appendices.

Comment: Silverman and I (Compositio 1991) gave a condition, satisfied by most curves, which implies that for those curves no point is in the support of $W_n$ for infinitely many $n$ and gave examples of curves for which there are such points.

Comment: This article by Cukierman and Fong seems relevant : http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~fcukier/pdfs/higherweierstrass.pdf‎ . In particular, it shows (theorem 6.1) that in genus $3$, $W^1\subset W^2$, but that otherwise if $g>3,n\geq 1$ or $g=3, n>2$, the universal divisor $\mathcal{W}_g^n$ is irreducible, so doesn't contain another one.